# Trying to make last li stretch to edge of the screen

Tags: css, menu, html-lists

I've styled a horizontal menu using background color, border-radius and negative left margin (probably get slated for the negative margin but I don't know any other way), you can see this here: http://tinyurl.com/nu6ltcy

CSS:

```
#menu-menu-1        {text-align: left; background: #FBBF7E;}
#menu-menu-1 li     {float: left; width: 26%; min-width: 150px; border: 1px solid #766341; border-width: 0; border-radius: 0 0 0 35px; -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 35px; -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 35px;}
#menu-menu-1 li a   {display: block; height: 62px; width: 100%; color: #fff; line-height: 62px; text-align: center;}
#menu-menu-1 li.current-menu-item a {font-weight: bold;}
#menu-menu-1 li#menu-item-13        {background: #766341; }
#menu-menu-1 li#menu-item-14        {background: #F78F1E; margin-left: -35px;}
#menu-menu-1 li#menu-item-17        {background: #F7A54C; margin-left: -35px;}
#menu-menu-1 li#menu-item-15        {background: #FBBF7E; margin-left: -35px;}
```

As you can see, the 4th (last) li stops about 30 pixels short of the edge because of the negative margin, could someone please advise how to fix this issue? Or a better method of making the li's overlap without using negative margin?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, using negative margins for this is not bad..

What I would do to make it fit right, is this:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3s74b8y6/2/)

### css

```
#menu-menu-1 li {
   float: left;
   width: 30%; /* 4 li's (25%) plus the 5% negative margin. */
   min-width: 150px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   margin-left: -5%; /* 5% is high enough to hide border edges in lower resolutions */
}
#menu-menu-1 li#menu-item-13 {
   background: #FEF4E8;
   margin: 0px;
   width: 25%; /* No negative margin so width stays 25% */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
#menu-menu-1        {text-align: left; background: #FBBF7E;}
#menu-menu-1 li     {float: left; width: 27.2422%; border: 1px solid #766341; border-width: 0; border-radius: 0 0 0 35px; -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 35px; -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 35px;}
#menu-menu-1 li a   {display: block; height: 62px; width: 100%; color: #fff; line-height: 62px; text-align: center;}
#menu-menu-1 li.current-menu-item a {font-weight: bold;}
#menu-menu-1 li#menu-item-13        {background: #766341; }
#menu-menu-1 li#menu-item-14        {background: #F78F1E; margin-left: -3%;}
#menu-menu-1 li#menu-item-17        {background: #F7A54C; margin-left: -3%;}
#menu-menu-1 li#menu-item-15        {background: #FBBF7E; margin-left: -3%;}
```